# How to format this mysql Query

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

What I have is a table statistieken with an ip, hash of browser info, url visited and last visited date in timestamp.

What I could compile from different sources led to this query, the only problem is that this query takes forever(9 minutes) to complete on a table with about 15000 rows, so this query is very inefficient.

I think I'm going to this the wrong way around, but I can't find a decent post or tutorial how to use the results of a select as basis for getting the results I want.

What I simply want is an overview of every entry in the table that matches the hash of the results that are returned that have visted more than 25 pages in the last 12 hours.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statsitieken` (
  `hash` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `visits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastvisit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `browserinfo` text NOT NULL,
  `urls` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is the query I have tried to compile so far.

```
SELECT * FROM `database`.`statsitieken` WHERE hash in (SELECT hash FROM `database`.`statsitieken`
where `lastvisit` > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(
                                    NOW(),INTERVAL 12 hour
                                    )
                                )
group by hash
having count(urls) > 25
order by urls)
```

I need this to compile in a decent time, like < 1 second which should be possible in my opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trying this modified query. The subquery is now computed only once instead of being run for each record returned:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM `database`.`statsitieken` s, (SELECT *
FROM `database`.`statsitieken`
WHERE `lastvisit` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 HOUR))
GROUP BY hash
HAVING COUNT(urls)>25) tmp
WHERE s.`hash`=tmp.`hash`
ORDER BY s.urls
```

Be sure you have indexes on the following fields:

- `hash` to speed up the `GROUP BY` and `WHERE`
- `urls` to speed up the `ORDER BY`

Comment: The problem with that one is I don't get the individual urls that person has visited

Comment: Thank you. Now I can see why this one works and my didn't. Thank you for enlightening me!

Answer (score 0):

Derived table with `INNER JOIN` is faster than a subquery. try this optimized query:

```
SELECT *
FROM statsitieken a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT hash
                FROM statsitieken
                WHERE lastvisit > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(
                                    NOW(),INTERVAL 12 hour
                                    )
                ) b
        ON a.hash = b.hash
GROUP BY a.hash
HAVING COUNT(urls) > 25
ORDER BY urls;
```

For better performance of this select query you should add indexes as:

```
ALTER TABLE statsitieken ADD KEY ix_hash(hash);

ALTER TABLE statsitieken ADD KEY ix_lastvisit(lastvisit);
```

Comment: It gives en error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b ON a.hash = b.hash GROUP BY a.hash HAVING COUNT(urls) ' at line 8` Also, this squishes the hashes together and I still don't get the individual urls that person has visited

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE hash in (SELECT hash FROM `database`.`statsitieken`
where `lastvisit` > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(
                                    NOW(),INTERVAL 12 hour
                                    )
                            )
```

You are "subquerying" (i don't know if exists that word :P, 'doing a subquery') in the same table, why not to:

```
where `lastvisit` > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(
                                    NOW(),INTERVAL 12 hour
                                    )
```

do it directly?

Comment: Because of the specific things I want to do with it. If I put it all in one query it gets squished by the group by and stuff. So first I need to get all the hashes that fit my parameters, then I can fetch the information I need that have those hashes.

Comment: ahhh ok, no objection then :P